# How can I get android phone to work with deadwood dns server on windows

Tags: android, windows, dns

I have installed the deadwood recursive dns service on my windows 11 pc. I am able to resolve domain names successfully on the windows machine itself. Problem is, I have set up my Android 10 phone to use the ip of the windows system as the dns for the local wifi network. But when I try to resolve the names on the Android's browsers, I get the ip address could not be found error.
My dwood3rc.txt looks like this:

```
bind_address="192.168.1.144, 0.0.0.0"
recursive_acl = "192.168.1.1/24, 0.0.0.0/0"
cache_file = "dw_cache_bin"
#ip_blocklist = "10.222.33.44, 10.222.3.55"
filter_rfc1918 = 0

ip4 = {}
ip4["maradns.foo."] = "10.10.10.10"
ip4["kabah.foo."] = "10.11.11.11"
ip4["meeting.dev."] = "192.168.1.144"
ip4["isike.app."] = "192.168.1.140"
```

None of these ips resolve on the Android phone. My static ip settings for the network on my Android looks like this:
[image: settings on android]
I am still able to get websites from the windows using the ip address http://192.168.1.144.
Please how do I get the Android to work with the Deadwood dns server?

Comment: Some Web browsers ignore system DNS settings and have their own DNS configuration. Also on Android there is the privacy DNS settings for overriding network specific DNS. Also make sure the DNS port of your Windows system is accessible from Android at all and not blocked by firewall or local router.

Comment: @Robert Android does indeed respect all of the above settings. The culprit was Windows defender firewall. I was not aware that the DNS's UDP port 53 was blocked by default. I have added an allow rule for that port and everything works well now.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that all of the above settings were correct. The culprit was Windows Defender firewall. I was not aware that it blocked the UDP port 53 by default. Now I have added an allow rule for that port and everything works well. I am now able to have my android refer to development servers on my Windows pc by domain names, using the deadwood DNS.